# How to sort an XML in java?

Tags: java, xml

How can i sort this according to author name? single book can have multiple Author as well and multiple authors need to be sorted as well ? How to sort my xml ?

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <author>Nithish,Minupuri</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <       </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
   <       </book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Parse the XML into POJOs, sort the books, then re-generate the XML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Keep in mind that XML is not really meant to be sorted. If the consumer of the XML requires a "sort" or "sequence" of data, you should better go with a "sort" attribute on the book tag. E.g. `<book id="bk101" sort="7">` to indicate that this book should be on the seventh position. The consumer should then do the sorting of the data, based on that information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of sorting XML "in-place".

```java
String xml = "<catalog>\r\n" + 
             "   <book id=\"bk101\">\r\n" + 
             "      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>\r\n" + 
             "      <author>Nithish,Minupuri</author>\r\n" + 
             "      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>\r\n" + 
             "   </book>\r\n" + 
             "   <book id=\"bk102\">\r\n" + 
             "      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>\r\n" + 
             "      <title>Midnight Rain</title>\r\n" + 
             "   </book>\r\n" + 
             "   <book id=\"bk109\">\r\n" + 
             "      <author>Kress, Peter</author>\r\n" + 
             "      <title>Paradox Lost</title>\r\n" + 
             "   </book>\r\n" + 
             "</catalog>";
```

```java
// Parse XML
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
Element catalogElem = document.getDocumentElement();

// Find <book> elements
List<Element> bookElems = new ArrayList<>();
for (Node child = catalogElem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling())
    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child.getNodeName().equals("book"))
        bookElems.add((Element) child);

// Replace <book> elements with placeholders so interleaved whitespaces can be retained
List<Node> placeholders = new ArrayList<>();
for (Node bookElem : bookElems) {
    Node placeholder = document.createTextNode("X");
    catalogElem.replaceChild(placeholder, bookElem);
    placeholders.add(placeholder);
}

// Sort <book> elements by title
bookElems.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent()));

// Put <book> elements back into XML document
for (int i = 0; i < bookElems.size(); i++)
    catalogElem.replaceChild(bookElems.get(i), placeholders.get(i));

// Print the XML
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><catalog>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
   </book>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <author>Nithish,Minupuri</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
</catalog>
```